# race condition in my mongodb updates ? (using meteor)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor with MongoDB and I seem to have a problem with batch-updates that I run in the background. Periodically, a job runs that goes over all elements in one collection and updates them. It should update or add, but it duplicates fields instead.

I wrote a few helper functions, which should ensure that only available resources are taken and the collection is updated properly:

```
static getStore(warehouse, resource) {
    return warehouse.storage.find(x => x.resource == resource)
}

static getStoreAmount(warehouse, resource) {
    let store = this.getStore(warehouse, resource)
    if (store) {
        return store.amount
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

static addToStorage(warehouse, resource, amount) {
    if (amount <= 0) return true;
    console.log("adding "+amount+" "+resource)
    let store = this.getStore(warehouse, resource)

    // TODO: check if enough storage space is left
    // FIXME: somehow, something created a duplicate entry for grain here (from 2 fields) - async database calls?
                // with 3 fields, it gets added 3 times - definitely reliably bugged :-(
    // FIXME: somehow, despite adding twice, nothign was left - again async update call just before $pull'ing it?

    if (store) {
        Warehouses.update({"_id":warehouse._id, "storage.resource": resource}, {
            $set: {
                "storage.$.amount": store.amount + amount
            }
        })
    } else {
        Warehouses.update({"_id":warehouse._id}, {
            $push: {
                storage: {
                    resource: resource,
                    amount: amount,
                    buy: { amount: 0, price: 0 },
                    sell: { amount: 0, price: 0 }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    return true
}

static checkTakeFromStorage(warehouse, resource, amount, min=1) {
    if (amount <= 0) return 0;
    let have = this.getStoreAmount(warehouse,resource)
    if (have < min) {
        return 0
    }
    console.log("taking "+amount+" "+resource)
    if (amount >= have) {
        // FIXME: don't pull if we have buy or sell values !
        amount = have
        // $pull is tricky because of meteor limitations, so here is a workaround I found on the Internet:
        let raw = Warehouses.rawCollection()
        let findOneAndUpdate = Meteor.wrapAsync(raw.findOneAndUpdate, raw)
        findOneAndUpdate({_id: warehouse._id}, {
            $pull: { storage: { resource: resource }}
        })
    } else {
        Warehouses.update({"_id":warehouse._id, "storage.resource": resource}, {
            $set: {
                "storage.$.amount": have - amount
            }
        })
    }

    return amount
}
```

the data structure is like this:

```
warehouses {
 ...various things...
storage: [
{ resource: "a", amount: 123 },
{ resource: "b", amount: 456 },
...
]
}
```

however, when I run the batch job, contrary to my intended code, multiple entries are made in the storage table for the same resource. I'm probably doing my updates in a stupid way and there is probably a proper meteor/mongo way to do them that guarantees this cannot happen, but I couldn't find it when I searched for it, due to the fact that I update an array in an embedded document.

Comment: You refer to the above as "helper" functions. You're not running them as part of a blaze layout are you? What's triggering the batch updates?

Comment: No, I'm running them on the server side. They are triggered by a shell command during testing, in production a job (using msavin:sjobs) will be triggering them.